# Cannot map GraphQL Float to Springboot REST controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am trying to create a REST endpoint that will return a list of factories according to their latitude and longitude.

I have the following schema for a `Factory`:

```
type Query {
    factoriesByLocation(location_long: Float!, location_lat: Float!): [Factory]
}

type Factory {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    location_long: Float!
    location_lat: Float!
}
```

I have created a REST controller:

```java
public class FactoryController {

    @QueryMapping
    public List<Factory> factoriesByLocation(@Argument double location_lat, @Argument double location_long) {

        return FactoryService.getFactoriessByLocation(location_lat, location_long, 5.00);

    }

}
```

When I send a GraphQL query:

```json
query factoryDetails {
  factoriesByLocation(location_lat: 23.456, location_long: 78.901) {
    id
  }
}
```

I get an `IllegalStateException`:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal argument
Class [dev.me.services.factories.graphql.api.FactoryController]
Method [public java.util.List<dev.me.services.factories.graphql.entities.Factory> dev.me.services.factories.graphql.api.FactoryController.factoriesByLocation(double,double)] with argument values:
[0] [null],
[1] [null]